# How to make third party magento extension compatible with store theme.

Tags: magento

What is best way to make third party extension compatible with store theme which is not default theme. I don't want to do following:
1) We can't modify extension css/phtml file becuase this will make up-gradation of extension because in that case our extension will go away.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest finding CSS from a standard Magento install and use that. Having the least styling possible will mean the most flexibility for the users. Also include instructions on where the file is by default and to install in their theme's template location. I believe this could be programmatically determined and be checked in the Admin area of your extension.